# PHP - Cannot get SOAP server to work

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have written a very simple SOAP Server to check access to the server but I'm getting an error.
The server is a brand new VM of Windows Server 2008R2 (which I installed today to check this) I then installed WAMP which is working correctly. I think the issue is more of a configuration one but I'm no expert from here so need some help finding it.

I have enabled SOAP in WAMP. The WSDL is fine, I have checked it on a hosted server and it works as expected along with the server and client php files.

The error received at the client:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
Couldn't load from './Soaptest.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "./Soaptest.wsdl" in 
C:\wamp\www\Connector\Testing\c20\c20simpleClient.php:7 
Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\Connector\Testing\c20\c20simpleClient.php(7): 
SoapClient->SoapClient('./c20simpleSoap...') #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\wamp\www\Connector\Testing\c20\c20simpleClient.php on line 7
```

The Soap Server:

```
function Test(){    
return true;
}

$server = new SoapServer("Soaptest.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("Test");
$server->handle();
```

The client (Line 6+):

```
$url = "./Soaptest.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
echo "client created<br>";
$result = $client->Test();
echo "<hr>Method Test: <pre>".(string)$result."</pre>";
```

Aside from enabling soap in the php config, is there anything I need to do in Apache or php to enable SOAP?

Comment: Well, you need to define a WSDL, which cannot be loaded at this point...

Comment: I have a wsdl `Soaptest.wsdl` which is in the same folder as the server and client. This works on a hosted server so why would the wsdl need to be different on this test server?

Comment: What do `var_dump(file_exists($url))` and `var_dump(is_readable($url))` output?

Comment: Btw is your production server also Windows based, or is it Linux?

Comment: both `var_dump(file_exists($url))` and `var_dump(is_readable($url))` output `boolean false`

Comment: Then PHP cannot see your WSDL file. Fix your paths.

Comment: production is Linux, but then I have also sent this to a friend who is on a basic Linux test server and they get the same error response (I'm assuming caused by the same issue but it's hard to tell)

Comment: There was a type in the path. I will return to it tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: remove ./ if evrything is in the same folder.